# How to get values of computed CSS color string?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, domdocument, computed-properties

I need to get the color value (any format, hex, rgb, etc.) of CSS color "names" or strings. Such as `"blue"` for example, I expect to return `"#0000ff"` or `"rgb(0, 0, 255)"`.

The specific color I need the value of is the `-moz-win-accentcolor`, available on Firefox to get the accent color set in the Windows 10 personalization settings.

I tried using computed styles in CSS with the following code, and resulted in `"rgb(57, 66, 69)"`. The color I have set in personalization is exactly that.

This is the code for that function:

```
const testInput0 = document.getElementById("test-input-0");
const testInput1 = document.getElementById("test-input-1");


function getWindowsAccentColor() {
    let coloredElement = document.createElement("span");
    coloredElement.style.backgroundColor = "-moz-win-accentcolor";
    let colorValue = getComputedStyle(coloredElement).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    coloredElement.remove();

    return colorValue;
}


testInput1.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let colorValue = getWindowsAccentColor();
    testInput0.value = colorValue;
    console.log(colorValue);
});
```

When I use this CSS color in my theme [Native Dark](https://github.com/spikespaz/firefox-nativedark), the value updates in time with changes (kind of, there are bugs in Issues about it). When using computed styles in the JS however, it stays with the old color **until I restart the browser completely**. But it does change properly.

Comment: Is it only your code that lags behind until you restart the browser, or can you tell if everything in the browser lags behind -- like if there are some parts of the browser itself that rely on the accent color? I'd say there's a good chance the browser only reads that color once at start-up and that's the best you're going to get.

Comment: @kshetline I don't know how the browser handles this, but the theme I linked is based on this color, and it does update in time with Windows. So this is the first time it has not updated as expected. Normal elements with this color also do not update seamlessly. I don't understand why my WebExtension does.

Comment: Maybe use `testInput0.style.backgroundColor = colorValue` instead of `testInput0.value = colorValue` as to affect style to an element from JavaScript you need to do it from its `style` object. As it is in the code you provide you only set the value of the input as the `colorValue` so don't expect color changes from this.